# Web scraping through pagination with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm web scraping data from [Bodybuilding.com](https://bodyspace.bodybuilding.com/member-search) for a course project and my goal is to scrape member information. I successfully scraped information on the 1st page for 20 members. The problem occurs when I go to the 2nd page. The highlighted portion below shows that index 21 to 40 repeats information from index 1 to 20. And, I don't know why.

I thought line 28 (bolded) would update the variable and the information it stores. But it doesn't seem to change. Does this have to do with the website structure?

I would appreciate any help, thanks.

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time
import json

data = {}

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://bodyspace.bodybuilding.com/member-search"
browser.get(url)

html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# Going through pagination
pages_remaining = True
counter = 1
index = 0

while pages_remaining:

    if counter == 60:
        pages_remaining = False

    # FETCH AGE, HEIGHT, WEIGHT, & FITNESS GOAL

    **metrics = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "bbcHeadMetrics"})**

    for x in range(0, len(metrics)):
        metrics_children = metrics[index].findChildren()

        details = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "bbcDetails"})
        individual_details = details[index].findChildren()

        if len(individual_details) > 16:
            print ("index: " + str(counter) + " / Age: " + individual_details[2].text + " / Height: " + individual_details[4].text + " / Weight: " + individual_details[7].text + " / Gender: " + individual_details[12].text + " / Goal: " + individual_details[18].text)
        else:
            print ("index: " + str(counter) + " / Age: " + individual_details[2].text + " / Height: " + individual_details[4].text + " / Weight: " + individual_details[7].text + " / Gender: " + individual_details[12].text + " / Goal: " + individual_details[15].text)

        index = index + 1
        counter = counter + 1

    try:
        # Go to page 2
        next_link = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Go to page 2"]')
        next_link.click()
        index = 0
        time.sleep(30)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        rows_remaining = False
```

Comment: I answered the question below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's necessary to update the variables html and soup.

```
try:
    # Go to page 2
    next_link = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Go to page 2"]')
    next_link.click()
    index = 0

    # update html and soup
    html = browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

    time.sleep(30)

except NoSuchElementException:
    rows_remaining = False
```

I believe you have to do it this way because the URL doesn't change and the html is being dynamically generated using javascript.

Comment: I think this solution work on going through the next pages. Just the same page results are coming.